# Typescript does not see my type-graphql useMiddleware function

Tags: typescript, prisma-graphql, typegraphql

I have a resolver for creating posts and adding the authorId as a foreign key from my session.

```js
@Mutation(() => PostType)
@UseMiddleware(isAuth)
async createPost(
       @Arg('title') title: string,
       @Arg('text') text: string,
       @Ctx() { prisma, req }: MyContext
): Promise<PostType> {
       return await prisma.post.create({
       data: {
        title,
        text,
        authorId: req.session.userId,
       },
        });
}
```

But typescript says that my userId on req.session may be undefined, even though I have an useMiddleware decorator with the isAuth function which looks like this

```js
import { MyContext } from 'src/types';
import { MiddlewareFn } from 'type-graphql';

export const isAuth: MiddlewareFn<MyContext> = ({ context }, next) => {
    console.log('isAuth middleware: ', context.req.session.userId);
    if (context.req.session.userId === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Not authenticated');
    }
    return next();
};
```

When I add the if block inside my resolver it works. I know I could also just `// @ts-ignore`  or cast `req.session.userId as number` but I don't know if there is another way to fix this

Comment: I imagine that `req` is the request of the corresponding framework. You need to tell TypeScript about the type(s): See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900537/typescript-extend-express-session-interface-with-own-class)

Comment: It's not that TypeScript doesn't know about the type of `req`. It even autocompletes to `userId`. But the type of userId inside my resolver is `number | undefined`. It should be just `number` because my middleware only runs the resolver if `userId` is not undefined

Comment: Leveraging the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74049208/6676781, see [This Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cz5htb?file=index.ts&view=editor)